# How to have login form work with symfony2 security

Tags: php, security, symfony

This is my setting for security login

```
form_login:
                # the user is redirected here when he/she needs to login
                login_path:                     /login

                # if true, forward the user to the login form instead of redirecting
                use_forward:                    false

                # submit the login form here
                check_path:                     /login_check

                # by default, the login form *must* be a POST, not a GET
                post_only:                      true
```

I want to ask that do i need make controllers and define route for /login and /login check

because i dont have those routes defined anywhere

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use the `FOSUserBundle` everything is made for you.

https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSUserBundle